# C# LINQ - Map a flat list of children and parents to a hierarchical list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I use this LINQ code for select a **flat** list of children and their parents from an SQL DB:

```
 (from c in _context.Children
  join cp in _context.ChildParents on c.Id equals cp.ChildId
  join p in _context.Parents on cp.ParentId equals p.Id
  select new ChildWithParentFlat()
     {
      ChildId = c.Id,
      ChildName = c.Name,
      ParentId = p.Id,
      ParentName = p.Name
     }
 ).ToList();
```

It brings up a list in this format:

```
[
{
    "ChildId": 1,
    "ParentId": 1,
    "ChildName": "FirstChild",
    "ParentName": "FirstParent"
},
{
    "ChildId": 1,
    "ParentId": 2,
    "ChildName": "FirstChild",
    "ParentName": "SecondParent"
},
{
    "ChildId": 2,
    "ParentId": 3,
    "ChildName": "SecondChild",
    "ParentName": "ThirdParent"
},
{
    "ChildId": 2,
    "ParentId": 4,
    "ChildName": "SecondChild",
    "ParentName": "FourthParent"
}
]
```

I want to convert this list to hierarchical list, so that each object will contain a child with its parents. something like this:

```
[
{
    "ChildId": 1,      
    "ChildName": "FirstChild",        
    "Parents": [
        {
            "ParentId": 1,
            "ParentName": "FirstParent"
        },
        {
            "ParentId": 2,
            "ParentName": "SecondParent"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ChildId": 2,
    "Parents": [
        {
            "ChildName": "SecondChild",
            "ParentName": "ThirdParent",
        },
        {
            "ParentId": 4,
            "ParentName": "FourthParent"
        }
    ]
},

]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: using Linq groupBy?

Comment: YOu have to post all 3 classes if you need a real help, not just speculations

Comment: You want to convert this list or you want to get that hierarchical list directly from database?

Comment: @J.Salas, Can you demonstrate how?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I want to convert this list. I do not think it is possible to pull it from the database in this structure.

Comment: @Serge, Is the desired structure not understood according to the JSON?

Comment: @levi No, we need to see the relations between classes, to find the best way. I don't want to waste my time guessing,  you should cooperate too.

Comment: Unrelated to finding your answer, but when picking your starting table to join from, you want to pick the side of the relationship that is "inflated" or the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship. In this case I'm talking about starting from `_context.ChildParents` and joining the other two tables from there. This link explains it well: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12098#issuecomment-391095895

Comment: @AustinArnett, I will take it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to convert this list to hierarchical list

Use `GroupBy`:

```
var hyrarchical = flatList
   .GroupBy(x => (x.ChildId, x.ChildName))
   .Select(cg => (
       ChildId: cg.Key.ChildId, 
       ChildName: cg.Key.ChildName,
       Parents: cg.GroupBy(x => (x.ParentId, x.ParentName))
                  .Select(pg => (ParentId: pg.Key.ParentId, ParentName: pg.Key.ParentName))) 
   ));
```

You can add `ToList` where needed, you could also use a custom class instead of these tuples,

Comment: Tuples are not supported in Expression Trees.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: That's Linq-To-Objects, of course they are supported

Comment: You are right. Missed this transformation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!